# K-means clustering KDDcup99 data set error

Tags: matlab, k-means

I am using `idx = kmeans(kddcup,5);` for kmeans clustering. 145586 records with 41 features of kddcup99, 10% subset of database into 5 clusters, but MATLAB r2017a gives this error:

> Kmeans cannot accept complex data!

I loaded a database in MATLAB that has 42 columns instead of 41, which means that the 42nd column is for type of row (attack, normal, ...) and is not a feature, and I don't know if I should keep that 42nd row or delete it.

I don't know if my work is correct or if there is a mistake in that code.

Comment: So the 42' column is a nominal variable? Kmeans doesn't work with that.

Comment: Stop using the KDDcup99 data set. It's bad.

Answer (score 0):

idx = kmeans(X,k)  [see documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kmeans.html)  requires numeric input for X.

> Data, specified as a numeric matrix. The rows of X correspond to
>   observations, and the columns correspond to variables.
>
> If X is a numeric vector, then kmeans treats it as an n-by-1 data
>   matrix, regardless of its orientation.
>
> Data Types: single | double

You will need to not pass the 42nd column of `kddcup` to `kmeans`.

Since you said that `kddcup` contains (attack,normal,...) are those `char`?  So, what datatype is `kddcup`?

Regardless it will need to stripped of the 42nd column and possibly converted into a numeric matrix if it isn't already.

Comment: thank you dear: for example this is 1 row of database :0 /tcp/http/SF /181 /5450/0/0 /0/0/0/1/0 /0/0/0/0/0 /0/0/0/0/8 /8/0.00/0.00/0.00/0.00 /1.00/0.00/0.00/9/9/1.00/0.00/0.11/0.00/0.00/0.00/0.00/0.00/normal.  whit 41 feature  and data base have 145586 record like that. my base article for study, use kmeans clustering and say that after clustering the database reduce from 145586 to116266 and it is compact dataset for work,  but i dont know how they do that, in article say dat because the database have 5 classes we cluster data into 5 cluster, please help me please